# Passing docker-compose args to ENTRYPOINT script

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
...
build:
  context: myimg
  args:
    - FOO=bar
```

And my dockerfile does this:

```
...
ARG FOO
ENTRYPOINT run.sh
```

However, my script can't see the `FOO` var...

Inside run.sh:

```
echo $FOO
```

Outputs nothing. I have tried several combinations of the shell and exec forms and passing the vars as env vars but nothing works. I need to pass them down as env vars, not params.

Comment: You entrypoint should be able to read ENV vars that are set in the docker-compose file. Have you tried that? `environment:
      - FOO=BAR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args:` *only* affect building the initial image, and the initial image build isn't aware of any of the rest of the context you might define in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

If you're hoping to use this for runtime configuration, an `environment:` setting will be better.  Unlike build-time arguments, you won't have to rebuild the image just to change the environment variable setting.  Remove the `ARG` line from the `Dockerfile` and change the `docker-compose.yml` file to say

```
build:
  context: myimg
environment:
  - FOO=bar
```

If you want an `ARG` value to be visible as an environment variable later on (for instance in an `ENTRYPOINT` script) you need to add an `ENV` setting for it as well; there are [a couple of examples in the Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#using-arg-variables).  This might look like

```
FROM ...
ARG FOO
ENV FOO=$FOO
COPY run.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```